# Why should a kernel function satisfy Mercer's condition in ELM or SVM?

Tags: neural-network, svm

In kernalized ELM, they (www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/pdf/ELM-Unified-Learning.pdf) mentioned that a kernel should satistsfy Mercer's condition. I didn't find a specific reason behind that. Please explain the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is explained [here](http://www.svms.org/mercer/).
Let me quote it:

> Finally, what happens if one uses a kernel which does not satisfy Mercer�s condition? In general, there may exist data such that the Hessian is indefinite, and for which the quadratic programming problem will have no solution (the dual objective function can become arbitrarily large). However, even for kernels that do not satisfy Mercer�s condition, one might still find that a given training set results in a positive semidefinite Hessian, in which case the training will converge perfectly well. In this case, however, the geometrical interpretation described above is lacking."
>   Burgess (1998)

So without a kernel which is satisfying Mercer's condition, you lose at least some convergence guarantees (it's possible, that you lose even more: e.g. convergence-speed or approximation-accuracy when early-stopping)!